# How do I skip certain ValidateInterceptor?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I have created a `VariantValueCategory` and wanted to skip the `ValidateInterceptor` as it was not allowing me to create `VariantValueCategory` either by `Impex` or by `HMC`. Can any one suggest me how do I skip  `ValidateInterceptor` or any `Interceptor`?

Answer (score 19):

### Answer for hybris >= v6

*Check Mouad El Fakir's answer for previous version*

You can disable interceptor through code and Impex.

### Using code

You can run your save model code using `sessionService.executeInLocalViewWithParams` and you can use parameters to avoid to use interceptors.

There are 3 types of policies :

- `InterceptorExecutionPolicy.DISABLED_INTERCEPTOR_BEANS` : to disable a list of beans
- `InterceptorExecutionPolicy.DISABLED_INTERCEPTOR_TYPES` : to disable a kind of interceptor - validator for example
- `InterceptorExecutionPolicy.DISABLED_UNIQUE_ATTRIBUTE_VALIDATOR_FOR_ITEM_TYPES` : to disable `UniqueAttributesValidator`on a set of type

**Example 1 - Disable beans**

```
final Map<String, Object> params = ImmutableMap.of(InterceptorExecutionPolicy.DISABLED_INTERCEPTOR_BEANS, ImmutableSet.of("yourDataInterceptorToDisable"));

sessionService.executeInLocalViewWithParams(params, new SessionExecutionBody()
{
    @Override
    public void executeWithoutResult()
    {
        //Do your stuff  
        modelService.save(something);   // save successful - yourDataInterceptor interceptor is disabled
    }
});
```

**Example 2 - Disable interceptors type**

```
final Map<String, Object> params = ImmutableMap.of(InterceptorExecutionPolicy.DISABLED_INTERCEPTOR_TYPES,
                ImmutableSet.of(InterceptorExecutionPolicy.DisabledType.VALIDATE));
sessionService.executeInLocalViewWithParams(params, new SessionExecutionBody()
{
    @Override
    public void executeWithoutResult()
    {
        //Do your stuff  
        modelService.save(something);    // save successful - all validate interceptors are disabled
    }
});
```

**Example 3 - Disable by type**

```
final Map<String, Object> params = ImmutableMap.of(InterceptorExecutionPolicy.DISABLED_UNIQUE_ATTRIBUTE_VALIDATOR_FOR_ITEM_TYPES, ImmutableSet.of("YourType"));

sessionService.executeInLocalViewWithParams(params, new SessionExecutionBody()
{
    @Override
    public void executeWithoutResult()
    {
        //Do your stuff  
        modelService.save(something);   // save successful - UniqueAttributesValidator not called
    }
});
```

### Using Impex

It's the same thing with impex you can add 3 parameters to achieve the same thing as code

**Example 1 - Disable beans** `[disable.interceptor.beans='yourDataInterceptorToDisable']`

```
INSERT_UPDATE YourType[disable.interceptor.beans='yourDataInterceptorToDisable'];isocode[unique=true];toto;titi;
;something;toto;titi;
```

**Example 2 - Disable interceptors type** `[disable.interceptor.types=validate]`

```
INSERT_UPDATE YourType[disable.interceptor.types=validate];isocode[unique=true];toto;titi;
;something;toto;titi;
```

**Example 3 - Disable by type** `[disable.UniqueAttributesValidator.for.types='YourType']`

```
INSERT_UPDATE YourType[disable.UniqueAttributesValidator.for.types='YourType'];isocode[unique=true];toto;titi;
;something;toto;titi;
```

Ref : https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/9ce1b60e12714a7dba6ea7e66b4f7acd.html

Comment: Awesome, i didn't know that it's possible to disable a specific interceptor from impex.

Comment: @MouadELFakir Yes I guess it's quite new. I've not heard of it while I was working on 5.4. Actually your answer is good for version before 6 because above code probably won't work.

Answer (score 10):

Actually there are two **modes** of importing data with **ImpEx** in Hybris :

- **Active mode** : it uses the `ServiceLayer` to do import. It means that actions like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `REMOVE` are performed using `ModelService`, thus the `ServiceLayer` infrastructure like `interceptors` and `validators` are triggered.
- **Legacy mode** : it's a very quick `CRUDE` import, which means it's bypassing the `ServiceLayer` of Hybris, hence no `interceptors` and no `validators` are invoked.

So how to enable **legacy mode** ? will You can do this in three different ways :

1. In `local.properties` set `impex.legacy.mode = true` and restart the server.

```xml
<!-- local.properties -->

impex.legacy.mode = true
```

2. Or if you do import using `HAC`, check `legacy mode` checkbox :

[image]

3. Or set the configuration directly into the`impex` like this :

```csv
INSERT_UPDATE VariantValueCategory[impex.legacy.mode=true] ;myAttribute
...
```

---

However if you want to disable completely the `interceptor` from being called (not just for impexes), you can replace it with a `VoidInterceptor`.

> VoidInterceptor : it's an empty interceptor, it does nothing at all.

So if we suppose that you want to prevent this interceptor `variantCategoryValidateInterceptor` from being invoked, you can replace it like this :

```xml
<!-- in my*-spring.xml -->

<bean id="variantValueCategoryVoidInterceptorMapping" class="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.InterceptorMapping">

    <property name="interceptor" ref="VoidInterceptor"/>

    <property name="typeCode" value="VariantValueCategory"/>

    <property name="replacedInterceptors" ref="variantCategoryValidateInterceptor"/>

</bean>
```

Comment: The `impex.legacy.mode` way was to aggressive, it bypass all interceptors. You can't be precise and just skip one specific validator. There are now cleaner way to disable interceptor. Please check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way: **unregisterInterceptor**

Go to HAC -> Scripting Languages -> Groovy

```
def inteceptorMapping = spring.getBean("yourInterceptorMappingBeanId")
registry = spring.getBean("interceptorRegistry");
registry.unregisterInterceptor(inteceptorMapping);
```